# Alias Command Execution using paramiko

Tags: python

I have created a python script and login to a remote machine via ssh using `paramiko`.
On remote machine alias commands are created so try to execute them from my script gives me error as `"command not found"` but these command works fine when I do ssh manually and run them. What is the error ?

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()) 
client.connect(rms_ip, username='msat',password='oneweb123',port=22)
stdin, stdout, stderr 
=client.exec_command('dumpActiveContacts',get_pty=True)
print(stdout.read())
client.close()
```

Alias command using `paramiko` on remote server.

Comment: please post the full error message for increased clarity

Comment: bash: dumpActiveContacts: command not found

Comment: This is the error message